# Export markup html fields to csv, character encoding - Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I have text field in Jasper report jrxml template marked as html. This property removes any HTML tags from text and it works fine as html export, as pdf, excel...etc.

Only issue is csv export. It shows strange characters on tags positions.

[image]

Changing default encoding from 'UTF-8' to 'ISO-8859-1' did not give results.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.character.encoding" value="ISO-8859-1"/>
```

Anyone knows solution?

Thanks

Comment: I think jasper server should stay as tag, since it can be related to setting jasper configuration to support correct encoding on export. @Alex K

Comment: Is everything works fine from iReport/JSS or Java code?

Comment: Its same problem when I do export from Jasper Studio, do not have Java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved issue

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.write.bom" value="true"/>
```